# Installing optional Java 7.x on WebSphere Application Server 7

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

How to configure explicitly java 7 on WAS 7 version ?

Please suggest

Answer (score 6):

Not possible for WAS 7. Java 7 is supported from WAS 8.5.x.

Comment: Yeah I agree, but still can't we point to other JVM instead of implicitly which it refers to its own IBM JVM ?

Answer (score 0):

External Java is supported only on few **selected Platforms** such as **HP-Unix**, **Solaris**. 
And can't be used with WAS 7 on Windows and All Linux. :(

Comment: But still it is still possible, i have seen in our one of client machine where they have mapped to Java 8